# Why Glob doesn't work while scandir is?

Tags: php

Can someone explain why, in this situation, scandir is getting my directory, but the glob is getting...well, it seems like it's getting the path:

```
$directory = "../../../XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/media/csv";
```

With scandir:

```
$files  = scandir($directory);
print_r($files);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => myCsv.csv [3] => index.html )
```

With Glob:

```
$files  = glob($directory . "*"); # i wanted to select only CSV, but it returned empty. so i placed a *.
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => ../../../XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/media/csv )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `$directory` is something like `../XXX/media/csv`, you need to append it with `/*.csv` so it would become `../XXX/media/csv/*.csv` (currently it is `../XXX/media/csv*`).

```
$files = glob($directory . "/*.csv");
```

Comment: ooo thank you, been searching around for an hour... (way to make me feel stupid :) )   - Consider accepted... in 9 minutes.